# Fatal exception in my andengine project: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo

Tags: android, eclipse, andengine

I can not run the andengine project due to this error:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
package a.a.a;

import org.anddev.andengine.engine.Engine;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.scene.Scene;
import org.anddev.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity;

public class AActivity extends BaseGameActivity
{
    Engine engine;
    public Engine onLoadEngine() 
    {
        return engine;
    }

    public void onLoadResources() 
    {
    }

    Scene scene;
    public Scene onLoadScene() 
    {
        return this.scene;
    }

    public void onLoadComplete()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Your stack trace says it cannot find the superclass, `BaseGameActivity`. did you follow the ["getting started"](http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/getting-started-with-andengine-t11.html) guide to ensure that the andengine JAR file is included in your application?

Comment: Would you mind including the _text_ of that error message in the question and not just a screenshot? _Never_ post an image when what you are showing is essentially just text...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your activity is declared in your manifest.

Comment: I'm sure but it's still the same

Answer (score 0):

you are returning null objects

you should initialize your Engine and scene before returning them

refer back to the base example code